# How to save a password properly

Tags: c#, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption, securestring

I attemt to write a program, with which you can login to a remote website. For some people having multiple accounts, I try to make it easy for them and store account data in `IsolatedStorage`. At the current state of my code, the password is just entered in a `TextBox` and as soon as it's stored converted to a MD5 hash.

Now I'd like to refactor this to proper code, but I got stuck.

A `PasswordBox` exposes its data through `PasswordBox.SecureString` and `PasswordBox.Password`.

So when clicking my save button I'd perform something like

```
public void OnClick(...)
{
    var password = passwordBox.Password;
    // store it somehow (e.g. custom MD5 encryption)

    var savePassword = passwordBox.SecureString;
    // store this string somehow, but how?
}
```

Here my questions

- As soon as I put the plain password from my `PasswordBox` into `var password`, is there something visible in memory? Would some *hacker* be able to make this plain value visible through reflection/debugging? Which code makes these strings actually visible? And what do I need to be aware of?
- How to handle `SecureString` of the `PasswordBox`?

I'm a bit overwhelmed by all this stuff and I can't figure out the essence of how to handle passwords in an application properly, yet.

I'm not pleading for a whole solution and running code. I'd just be glad, if someone can get me started. And also, I don't want an enterprise solution. I'm just searching for one, which is easy to implement and as save as possible for the effort I put in.

Comment: If the attacker can run a debugger or use reflection on private data *then they already own the system*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the password to be reversible?

A safer way to store it is to salt and hash it.

User: `JOHN`

Password: (starts out as) `myUserPassword667!`

Then use some sort of database unique code against the user in the DB.  Lets say a GUID.

Now you have `abcd-1234-12-1212121ab` as the uniquifier for JOHN

so you now have a base password(before hashing)

`myUserPassword667!abcd-1234-12-1212121ab`

You can now Hash this with one of the SHA or other hashing algorithms in the `System.Security` namespace.

Now you internally have some Salt that you Apply to your hashing algorithm... (Part of your code only)

`MySecretSaltWords559BC`

then store the Result as either a Base64 or Binary in your DB.

`Ab09l\311sas==` (simplified)

Next time the user logs on you find their record in the DB, you get your Unique code that was used when you generated the account and attach to the password they entered.

Hash the entered password with the same technique and binary compare the result, then you don't need to ever store their password. If the hashes don't match you don't have the same password.

Comment: I don't need it to be reversible and this is how it works at the moment. With your answer given, the only question I have is, how to get the plain password properly out of the `PasswordBox`? Is assigning the plain value of the password to a variable bad practice? How to deal with this?

Comment: I'd say use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securestring) append these to a memorystream, append your uniquifier and then feed into Sha. You can then Array.Clear the bytes from the Encoding and you can rewind your memorystream and fill with 0's before Disposing (if you want) or just Dispose